# Font File not loading in any browser

Tags: fonts, font-face

Live Example: https://portal.riits.net/ (please ignore the layout issues, it is still being worked on by UI designers).

The FontAwesome font is not being requested by any browser (I see no failed attempts at loading it in developer tools in Chrome, Firefox or IE) and thus the font-based icons are not being displayed.

These are the things I have checked:

1. Yes, the font is being requested explicitly by an element on the page.
2. Added all the additional font processing needed to Apache2 (made sure the application/types are defined, made sure the cross-origin policy is in the .htaccess file). But see #3.
3. Have run multiple different sniffers between my computer and the end point, all of which appear to show the font file is never event requested.
4. This works fine in all local development environments where it has also been deployed.

I feel like I'm missing something really stupidly simple here.

Answer (score 1):

The link for the font-awesome css its not present on your page, so it wont be loaded, the problem its not the browser, its the code on the page

You are simply missing the import

For the look of it you are using Drupal, I would recomend using this module https://www.drupal.org/project/fontawesome

Or refer to http://fontawesome.io/get-started/ is pretty straightforward: 
Youll need at least a

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Or a

```
@import url(https://portal.riits.net/path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);
```

Comment: The link is present in linked CSS: nuboot_radix.style.css

Comment: @font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome' !IMPORTANT;
  src: url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0) !IMPORTANT;
  src: url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0) format("woff2"), url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0) format("woff"), url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0) format("truetype"), url(../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular) format("svg") !IMPORTANT;
  font-weight: normal !IMPORTANT;
  font-style: normal !IMPORTANT; }

Comment: Thisi is not our code--this is from the DKAN drupal project. As I said, it has worked as-is multiple other places.

Comment: https://portal.riits.net/profiles/dkan/themes/contrib/nuboot_radix/assets/css/nuboot_radix.style.css?orm4fk  search on FontAwesome to find the setup for the locally hosted font files.

Comment: And you can check the locally hosted versions of the files, they download when accessed directly: https://portal.riits.net/profiles/dkan/themes/contrib/nuboot_radix/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0

Comment: Are you using the theme? if you have the radix theme not selected it wont load the icons, check this: https://github.com/NuCivic/dkan/issues/729 says: "Using the latest dkan_dataset 7.x-1.9: file icons are broken if the site does not use the nuboot_radix theme"

Comment: We are using an internally developved subtheme of nuboot radix, generated using their subtheming system.

Comment: Although that did give me an idea, and I temporarily shut down our subtheme and redeployed the main nuboot radix theme. The font icons were still broken :(